# how to handle scd type2 updates in the fact table

Tags: mysql, etl

How to handle scd type2 updates in the fact table ?
I am not doing incremental loading on the fact table. Any good approach to follow. Can anyone suggest me so that i can follow the same approach when i am loading the data into the fact table.

ETL(Pentaho)

Answer (score 0):

I would

a) update dimension table A

b) get max(A.surrogate_key) value for the record(s) you just updated

c) insert a new record into your fact table with A.SURROGATE_KEY as record id

Try something like that?